# wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..1) after upgrading to Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I just upgraded from Rails 5.2 to Rails 6 and I'm facing an issue in one class.

```
class Calculator < ApplicationRecord
  def initialize(obj, user_id, calc_type, will_id = nil )
    @inheritors = obj
    super_obj = obj.clone.merge!(user_id: user_id, type: calc_type, will_id: will_id)
    super(super_obj)
    @shares = {}
    @remains = RationalWithArgumentStore(0)
    @stop_residual_shares = false
    @special_case_apply = false
    @rules = {}
    @authorities = {}
  end
end
```

and I'm creating new instance of the class like the following

```
calc = Calculator.new(obj, user_id, calc_type, nil)
```

It through an error saying:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..1)
```

I spent two days searching and trying to fix the issue without any luck.
Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are redefining `initialize` for a class that inherits from `ApplicationRecord`. It throws an error [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1421ad5c81910026ae54477fe244a40ed666122d/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L50). If you were to do the following it would work.

```
class Calculator
  def initialize(obj, user_id, calc_type, will_id = nil)
    @obj = obj
    @user_id = user_id
    @calc_type = calc_type
    @will_id = will_id
  end
end
```

Note that redefining `initialize` in this way is not recommended (see docs [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_callbacks.html)), so if you can I would look into callbacks and see if you can accomplish your goal with that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also factory can be a good choice here. `def Calculator.produce(super_obj); Calculator.new(...).tap { |calc| calc.user = ...... } end`.

Answer (score 0):

(Rails 6.x) One of my models had `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`.

If you have the same problem, remove it and manage your url methods by calling it directly as:

```rb
def my_link_function
 # ... my code
 my_link = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for([my_params]))
 # ... other code
end
```